# Suite setup and teardown for every test case file in a directory

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

My test suite is **a directory with multiple test case files**. When executing this directory I would like to run **the same `Suite Setup` before and `Suite Teardown` after most of the files**. But there are few that don't need it. I tried to use initialization file with `Suite Setup` and `Suite Teardown` but they are executed only once - `Suite Setup` before the first file and `Suite Teardown` after the last one. So it worked only when I included one file from the directory.

Is there any other way of doing this other than adding `Suite Setup` and `Suite Teardown` in multiple files from the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way of doing this other than adding Suite Setups and Teardowns in multiple files from the folder?

No, there is not. At least, not in any convenient way. You could attach a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) when running the tests, and have the listener run your setup code, but it's too easy to forget to add the listener.

In my experience, the simplest solution is to add a `Suite Setup` and `Suite Teardown` in every file. I've found that the overhead of doing that is minimal, and gives each file complete control over its setup. I've found that trying to enforce a universal setup for all suites in a folder is more trouble than it's worth.

If you want the setup to be identical for different test files, move all of the setup code into a common keyword, and call that keyword from the `Suite Setup` in every file.